# How to write the following program for 8086 Assembly?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

The latest eleven readings of Barometric pressure are stored in an array. Write a program to find
the average of odd addressed elements of the array and even addressed elements of the array
separately and store the values in OddAvg and EvenAvg variables and display the message
“Average found” using DOS Interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the tag [`emu8086`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emu8086) and find an answer which will show you how to *display the message using DOS Interrupt*.

The average is defined as a sum of values divided by the number of those values. There are instructions in x86 architecture for adding [ADD](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/add) and division [DIV](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/div).

Register `AX` is usually used to accumulate the sum of values. Increment `CX` after each addition, so it will end up with the number of values (five or six), then do `SUB DX,DX` and `DIV CX` to obtain the average in `AX`.

Register `SI` is the best for addressing of your array, start with the odd address and increase it after each addition to point at the next **odd** element. Then repeat the calculation with **even** addresses.

Comment: If you sum into AX, you'd need to zero-extend into another register.  Otherwise, `add ax, [si]`, you'd be doing SWAR addition of the even elements into AL, and the odd elements into AH.  (Assuming they don't overflow...)  That's assuming the input elements are 8-bit integers in the first place.

Comment: @PeterCordes That's a good optimisation idea, to calculate both addition into `AH` and `AL` with a single `ADD AX,[SI]` when the elements are `int8`.  But barometric pressure in Pascals won't fit to the range 0..255, I'm afraid, so the elements are probably `int16` or `int32`, who knows?

Comment: The question says odd **address** (not index), which if accurate implies bytes.  But yeah, nobody knows, so it's not usefully answerable yet.  Pressure in kPa would fit in an int8 (atmospheric pressure = 101), but you'd need a wider value to sum without overflow.